# How to troubleshoot and tweek unreasonably slow wireless connection?

Tags: 10.04, wireless, drivers, usb, performance

I've just acquired a `USB F5D8053ed Belkin` adapter and it is unreasonably slow.

Details of how I installed the firmware and device driver are described in [this AU Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49180/how-do-i-get-a-belkin-f5d8053-wireless-adapter-working).

I believe there is either a problem with a driver or adapter itself that is preventing from using the full network quality. At the moment I can see that my Windows laptop is performing at **30 x speed** better than the Ubuntu desktop PC with Belkin.

What are they ways to troubleshoot pure wireless network performance on Ubuntu?

Comment: last I heard Ubuntu had problems with wireless N not working properly yet, but I can't find that bug report where I saw the problem described.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the antenna in the USB dongle is horizontally polarized while the antenna on your access point is likely vertically polarized. Try using a short USB cable so the dongle can be situated vertically. That may help. I've a TRENDnet USB dongle that came with a very sort USB cable for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

On 10.10, Intel 5300 was limited from N to G only, due to kernel bugs. See: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1605338.html

I'd try to update the kernel in your position (see: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ ), or try to disable N mode somehow, but I think, for this one, updating the kernel would be easier.